# Entity Framework Core Creating a Many to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a many to many relationship using ef-core, and it definitely works, I am able to create each item in the database, and create a relationship. But the way I am doing it is a bit verbose. There also seems to be erroneous properties on the object in intellisense (I'll explain more below). I'm wondering if there is a different way.

Here are my entities

> DisplayItem.cs

```
public class DisplayItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public byte[] Item { get; set; }


        public ICollection<LookUpGroupItem> LookUpGroupItems { get; set; }
    }
```

> DisplayGroup.cs

```
public class DisplayGroup
    {
        [Key]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<LookUpGroupItem> LookUpGroupItems { get; set; }
    }
```

Relationship Entity

> LookUpGroupItem.cs

```
///naming convention will be each entity in the relationship following LookUp
 public class LookUpGroupItem
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public DisplayItem DisplayItem { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public DisplayGroup DisplayGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

Assume the model building logic is correct.
Here is the code I use to create each and then create the lookup relation.

> DisplayLookUpInteraction.cs

```
  public void Create(DisplayGroup g, DisplayItem d)
    {
        using (var transaction = _dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            try
            {
                _dataContext.Add(d);
                _dataContext.Add(g);
                _dataContext.SaveChanges();
                LookUpGroupItem l = new LookUpGroupItem() { GroupId = g.GroupId, ItemId = d.ItemId };
                _dataContext.Add(l);
                _dataContext.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
    }
```

This works fine, but again it seems a bit much. And now, whenever I work with `DisplayItem` or `DisplayGroup` there is always a property for the `ICollection<LookUpGroupItem>` within the object. What is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
try
{
    LookUpGroupItem l = new LookUpGroupItem 
    {
         DisplayGroup = g,
         DisplayItem = d
    };
    _dataContext.Add(l);
    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the error
}
```

When the `SaveChanges` method is executed with success then `ItemId` and `GroupId` properties will be configured with the correct values for you by EF.

You don't need a transaction because the single `SaveChanges` call will automatically trigger a transaction that will rollback all modifications if error is encountered.

Comment: I have deleted my comments and made another question @CodeNotFound